# Is this concept of classes, objects, and methods right?

Tags: class, object, methods, instance

I want to make sure that my understanding of the concepts of class, object, and instance are accurate so if I am wrong,  please provide feedback.

The class is "Human", with specifications such as height, weight, age, etc. Their methods are run, eat, talk, walk, and other actions.

These are the objects of the class "Human": Sally, Paul, Ray, Bob, with different values for the specifications.

One of these objects for example Sally, is an instance.

Did I get these right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.  It's an opinion based object oriented fundamental.

Comment: I just want a yes or no answer.

Comment: I think `Sally, Paul, Ray, Bob` should be a value of an attribute `name` with a type of String.

Comment: Should the name then be a specification of the humans? For example, Human1 has the specifications of Sally, 5'4'', 30, 130lbs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you add 'name' as a member variable of the class Human, then it would be correct to say that the object with the name 'Sally' is an instance of the Human class, though if it's at all possible that you could have two different humans named "Sally," you'd be wise to add an 'id' member variable which would be guaranteed to be unique.

The values of the member variables are not required for an 'instance,' though. You can create a new 'instance' of the Human class in which none of the member variables have values. It's still an instance of class Human and you could still call it's class methods (which might or might not work depending on how they're written and what they do).